# How do I add multiple inputs in a tableau with OTtablx-extras?

Tags: tables, linguistics

I'd like to make an optimality theoretic tableau with multiple inputs similar to this one (from [here](https://doi.org/10.1515/TLR.2006.001)):
[image: Multiple Input Tableau Example]
Up until now, I have been using the package [OTtablx-extras](https://github.com/anghyflawn/ottablx-extras) to make my tableaux, but only with single inputs. Now that I want multiple inputs, I simply do not know the package well enough to make it work and I haven't been able to find a manual or any examples. I do think though that it provides what I need with the OTmultitableau environment. Could somebody more knowledgeable with this package perhaps provide me an example from which I can work off of? Or point me towards some instance of the package in use?
Thank you.
Edit:
There does exist a manual for [OTtablx](http://sanders.phonologist.org/OTtablx/index.html), of which OTtablx-extras is a fork, but that package does not include an option for multiple inputs. The manual does not address my problem as far as I can tell.
As requested, here my code. Beware though that I do not know what I am doing. I'm using XeLaTeX to compile.
Single input:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{OTtablx-extras}

\begin{document}
\begin{OTtableau}{3}
        \OTsolids{1}\OTdashes{2}
        \OTtoprow[/test/]{x,y,z}
        \OTcandrow {a} {*,*,*}
        \OTcandrow [\OThand] {b} {,,}
\end{OTtableau}
\end{document}
```

Result:
[image: Single Input Tableau]
Easy enough.
My attempt at multiple inputs (more like a stab in the dark):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{OTtablx-extras}

\begin{document}
\begin{OTmultitableau}{3}
        \OTsolids{1}\OTdashes{2}
        \OTmtoprow[/test a/]{x,y,z}
        \OTmcandrow {a} {*,*,*}
        \OTmcandrow [\OThand] {b} {,,}
        \OTmtoprow[/test b/]{x,y,z}
        \OTmcandrow {a} {*,*,*}
        \OTmcandrow [\OThand] {b} {,,}
\end{OTmultitableau}
\end{document}
```

Result:
[image: Multiple Inputs Attempt]
Now, this looks much better than what I tried yesterday, but it is still wrong. Curiously, I don't get any error messages.
Other attempts include these two:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{OTtablx-extras}

\begin{document}
\begin{OTmultitableau}{3} %using the "normal" commands for a single input first
        \OTsolids{1}\OTdashes{2}
        \OTtoprow[/test a/]{x,y,z}
        \OTcandrow {a} {*,*,*}
        \OTcandrow [\OThand] {b} {,,}
        \OTmtoprow[/test b/]{x,y,z}
        \OTmcandrow {a} {*,*,*}
        \OTmcandrow [\OThand] {b} {,,}
\end{OTmultitableau}
\begin{OTmultitableau}{3}
        \OTsolids{1}\OTdashes{2}
        \OTmtoprow[/test a/]{x,y,z}
        \OTmcandrow {a} {*,*,*}
        \OTmcandrow [\OThand] {b} {,,}
        \OTmtoprow[/test b/] %{x,y,z} removing an argument
        \OTmcandrow {a} {*,*,*}
        \OTmcandrow [\OThand] {b} {,,}
\end{OTmultitableau}
\end{document}
```

Result:
[image: Multiple Inputs more failed attempts]
These look even worse than my "good" attempt, mainly because the changes to the code don't make much sense.
I'm starting to wonder whether the package is even supposed to do what I am trying here.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us the code you have so far, then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: Also, can you post a link to the package you're using. I don't think either OTtablx or OTtablx-extras are on CTAN and therefore not part of most people's distributions. The manual for OTtablx can be found [here](http://sanders.phonologist.org/OTtablx/index.html).

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I will edit my post accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution using plain `OTtablx` which is more recent than the code that the derivative package is made from.  We define an `\OTmcandrow` command which is identical to the `\OTcandrow` command except that it will not produce an enumerated candidate. Then you can build your multi-input tableau with no special environment needed, since you just have to intersperse `\OTcandrow` and `\OTmcandrow` commands as needed.   Here's the example tableau from the paper you cite. Due to the way the lines are drawn in `OTtablx`, it's difficult to remove the vertical lines from the enumerated candidates, so I can't reproduce the table exactly.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{OTtablx}
\makeatletter
\newcounter{OTx@candcount}
\renewcommand {\OTx@candrow} [3][\OTx@candmarker]
    {&\stepcounter{OTx@candidate}\stepcounter{OTx@candcount}\theOTx@candidate&#1~ 
     \OTx@candrowbasic{#2}{#3}}
\renewcommand {\OTx@candrowstar} [3][\OTx@candmarker]
    {&#1~ &\stepcounter{OTx@candidate}\stepcounter{OTx@candcount}\theOTx@candidate
     \OTx@candrowbasic{#2}{#3}}    
\renewcommand{\OTx@candrowbasic} [2]
    {&\OTx@textipa{#1}&\setcounter{OTx@xx}{1}
     \@for \xx :=#2 \do%
         {\expandafter\OTx@amp\xx\expandafter\OTx@amp\stepcounter{OTx@xx} }\\[-1.5ex]%
     \pnode{L\arabic{OTx@candcount}}&&&&\pnode{BD}%
     \setcounter {OTx@xx} {1}
     \whiledo
         {\value{OTx@xx} < \value{OTx@constraints}}
         {\expandafter\OTx@amp\expandafter\OTx@amp\pnode{B\arabic{OTx@xx}}
          \stepcounter{OTx@xx} }&
     &\pnode{R\arabic{OTx@candcount}}\\}
\renewcommand {\OTx@draw@rowsep}
    {\setcounter{OTx@xx}{1}%
    \whiledo {\value{OTx@xx} < \value{OTx@candcount}}
        {\psline[style=OTx@normal@style](L\arabic{OTx@xx})(R\arabic{OTx@xx})%
            \stepcounter{OTx@xx}}
}
\renewenvironment {OTtableau} [2][]                      %
    {\newcommand {\OTtoprow}                           % define \OTtoprow(*)
         {\@ifstar {\OTx@toprowstar}  {\OTx@toprow}}%  %
     \newcommand {\OTcandrow}                          % define \OTcandrow(*)
         {\@ifstar {\OTx@candrowstar} {\OTx@candrow}}% %
     \newcommand {\OTmcandrow}                          
         {\@ifstar {\OTx@mcandrowstar} {\OTx@mcandrow}}
     \SpecialCoor                                      % allow nodes as coordinates
     \gdef\OTx@draw@solids{}%                          % reset solids
     \gdef\OTx@draw@dashes{}%                          % reset dashes
     \gdef\OTx@draw@jagged{}%                          % reset jagged
     \setcounter {OTx@constraints} {#2}%               %
     \setcounter {OTx@specialcols} {2*#2 + 3}%         % special constraint columns
     \OTx@localoptions{#1}%                            % process tableau options
     \begin{tabular} [t] {@{}                          %
         p{0pt}                                        % left node column
         @{\hspace{0.5em}}r@{}r@{}l                    % label/marker/candidate column
         @{\hspace{0.5em}}p{\OTx@dblmid@lw}            % double separator column
         *{#2}                                         % special columns
         {@{\hspace{0.5em}}c@{\hspace{0.5em}}          %     constraint column
         p{0pt}}                                       %     constraint node column
         @{}}\\[-4.75ex]                               %
     \pnode{TL}&&&&\pnode{TD}&                         % top left and double nodes
     \setcounter {OTx@xx} {1}                          %
     \whiledo                                          %
         {\theOTx@xx < #2}                             %
         {\OTx@amp\pnode{T\theOTx@xx}\OTx@amp          % top constraint nodes
          \stepcounter{OTx@xx} }                       %
        &\pnode{TR}\\}                                 % top right node
                                                       %%%%% ENDING OF OTtableau
    {\rput(L\arabic{OTx@candcount}){\pnode{BL}}        % bottom left node
     \rput(R\arabic{OTx@candcount}){\pnode{BR}}\\[-3ex]% bottom right node
     \end{tabular}%                                    %
     \OTx@draw@rowsep%                                 % row separators
     \OTx@draw@solids%                                 % solid separators
     \OTx@draw@dashes%                                 % dashed separators
     \OTx@draw@double%                                 % double separators
     \ifthenelse {\boolean{OTx@closed}}                % closed/no border
         {\OTx@draw@dblmid%                            %     double middles
          \ifthenelse {\boolean{OTx@border}}           %
              {\OTx@draw@border}                       %     closed border
              {}}                                      %
         {\OTx@draw@border\OTx@draw@dblmid}%           % open border
     \OTx@draw@jagged}                                 % jagged separators

     
\newcommand {\OTx@mcandrow} [3][\OTx@candmarker]
    {&\stepcounter{OTx@candcount}&#1~ 
     \OTx@candrowbasic{#2}{#3}}
\newcommand {\OTx@mcandrowstar} [3][\OTx@candmarker]
    {&#1~ &\stepcounter{OTx@candcount}
     \OTx@mcandrowbasic{#2}{#3}}     

\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{OTtableau}{5}
        \OTsolids{2,3,4,5}\OTdashes{1}
        \OTtoprow{Agree,ID preson voi,ID-wf voi,IDvoi,*voi}
        \OTcandrow {/pigds/}{,,,,}
        \OTmcandrow {pigds} {!*,,,**}
        \OTmcandrow {pigdz} {,,*!,*,***}
        \OTmcandrow[\OThand] {pikts} {,,,**,}
        \OTcandrow {/pigts/}{,,,,}
        \OTmcandrow {pigts}{*!,,,,*}
        \OTmcandrow[\OThand]{pikts}{,,,*,}
        \OTcandrow{/pigtz/}{,,,,}
        \OTmcandrow[\OThand]{pigdz}{,,,**,***}
        \OTmcandrow{piktz}{*!,,,,}
        \OTmcandrow{pigts}{,,!*,*,}
\end{OTtableau}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Wow, that looks great! But there is something I must be doing wrong. I am using the newest version of OTtablx and I copy&pasted your code, but I receive the error message "Undefined control sequence." for \OTcandrow. It is quite verbose already, but if it helps, I could provide more specifics in my post.

Comment: @LHDStack My apologies, I was using a development version of the package that it seems Nathan never released, and it had some incompatible code. He and I worked on the package many years ago. I've updated the answer with code that works with the published version now.

Comment: That works great! For now, I will mark this question as solved, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way to achieve the same goal, but with the `ot-tableau` package, which is part of most distributions. The general approach is the same: the package defines a `\mcand` command which produces a candidate with no numbering. To remove the vertical lines for the enumerated candidate lines,  use the starred version of the `\vio` command to make cells with no vertical lines. [This is based on an earlier version of this answer which has now been included into the package].

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{ot-tableau}
\makeatletter

\LetterBeforeFinger
\usepackage{tipa}
\begin{document}
\LetterBeforeFinger
\begin{tableau}{c:c|c|c|c}
\inp{}        \const{Agree} \const{ID preson voi} \const{ID-wf voi} \const{IDvoi}\const{*voi}
\cand{\ips{pigds}} \vio*{}  \vio*{}     \vio*{} \vio*{} \vio{}
\mcand{pigds}   \vio{!*}    \vio{}      \vio{}  \vio{}  \vio{**}
\mcand{pigdz}    \vio{}     \vio{}      \vio{*!}    \vio{*} \vio{***}
\mcand[\Optimal]{pikts}    \vio{}       \vio{}      \vio{}  \vio{**}    \vio{}
\cand{\ips{pigts}}            \vio*{}       \vio*{}     \vio*{} \vio*{} \vio{}
\mcand{pigts}                   \vio{*!}    \vio{}      \vio{}  \vio{}  \vio{*}
\mcand[\Optimal]{pikts}    \vio{}       \vio{}      \vio{}  \vio{*} \vio{}
\mcand{pigdz}              \vio{}       \vio{}  \vio{!*}    \vio{**}    \vio{***}
\cand{\ips{pigtz}}            \vio*{}   \vio*{}     \vio*{} \vio*{} \vio{}  
\mcand[\Optimal]{pigdz}            \vio{}       \vio{}      \vio{} \vio{**} \vio{***}
\mcand{piktz}    \vio{*!}       \vio{}      \vio{} \vio{}   \vio{}
\mcand{pigts}     \vio{}        \vio{}  \vio{!*}    \vio{*} \vio{}
\end{tableau}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]